# Matching word inside multiple strings

Tags: bash, shell-script

Below code is working fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
str='fail'
var1='pass'
var2='ok'
var3='fail'
var4='pass'

case $str in
   $var1|$var2|$var3|$var4)
   echo yes
   ;;
   *) echo no
   ;;
esac
```

When I execute this, as expected I get output `yes`.

In above code, value of variables are not hard-coded, these are coming from previous run, so it keep changing. Here the problem is, sometime it comes like:

```
var3='partial|fail'
```

Any variable value can change like this. So in this case it gives `no`. What should I do change in my code so it handle this situation and match fail word and show the result `yes`?

Comment: Maybe the answer would be to change the code that generates your variables' content. What does it look like?

Comment: @lgeorget: Unfortunately that can not be changed. Whatever changes I have to do is only this code.

Comment: If `var3` has the value `partial|fail`, does this allow the two values `partial` and `fail` for `str`, or does it allow the one value `partial|fail`?

Answer (score 0):

```
       case $var1 in *"$str"* ) echo yes ;;
   * ) case $var2 in *"$str"* ) echo yes ;;
   * ) case $var3 in *"$str"* ) echo yes ;;
   * ) case $var4 in *"$str"* ) echo yes ;;
   * ) echo no ;; esac;; esac;; esac;; esac
```

With your approach we will have to resort to `eval`.

Another method:

```
unset -v f
A=( "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4" )
for var in "${A[@]}"; do case $var in *"$str"* ) f=; echo yes; break;; esac; done
${f+:} echo no
```

Comment: You can propose any better approach also if you have. I am not bounded with this only. :)

Comment: @serenesat As desired, another method has been proposed. You may want to test that.

Answer (score 0):

Do the `case` on *str*,

```
case $var1$var2$var3$var4 in
   *$str*) 
          echo yes 
   ;;
   *) 
          echo no 
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: This might generate `false positives`, viz., if some part of `$str` lies in one variable and other part lies in the next, then it would generate a yes whereas, technically speaking it shouldn't.

Comment: No with the data proposed by @serenesat

Comment: The data can be anything, not even the OP has a control over that. By that logic, if the data is fixed, we might just as well echo a yes in that scenario.

Comment: You can put an abbutal and then the method is general, in this case the "|" char that appears in the context of the problem is a good candidate, then the code looks,                                                                                        `case $var1"|"$var2"|"$var3"|"$var4 in *$str*) echo yes; ;; *) echo no; ;; esac`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
str="fail";
echo ${str} |awk -v var1="pass" \
-v var2="ok" \
-v var3="partial|fail" \
-v var4="pass" \
'{ if (( $0 ~ var1 ) || ( $0 ~ var2 ) || ( $0 ~ var3 ) || ( $0 ~ var4 )) {
  print "yes";
} else {
  print "no";
}}'
```

You can replace quoted var assignments above with on-the-fly values as needed.  If I've understood requirement, it is that "yes" be output whenever "str" is matched to some part of one of the vars?